# Xcode 11 (beta 4) can't compile my otherwise compiling project (under beta 3, 2 and 1): unrecognized compilation parameter -fstack-protector-all

Tags: ios, swift, compiler-errors, beta, xcode11

It's july and, probably as many developers in the iOS departments of many companies, our company is also testing the different betas of Xcode 11 whenever they get released in the Apple developer portal.

We're dealing with a somehow big solution made up of many pods, internal pods, sub-projects, etc...

Xcode 10.2.1 can compile it perfectly.

Xcode 11 beta 1 can also compile it (after some Realm issue solvable via Podfile and branching to some Realm fix branch)

Xcode 11 beta 2 can compile and test our complex solution without problem

Xcode 11 beta 3 can compile and test our complex solution wihtout problem

**Xcode 11 beta 4 can't even compile just a silly Swift file pertaining to any given module.**

What's the error Xcode gives? Something really strange as far as I understand:

```
<unknown>:0: error: unknown argument: '-fstack-protector-all'
Command CompileSwiftSources failed with a nonzero exit code
```

We've read the Xcode 11 beta 4 release notes from Apple, and we haven't found any known issue related with this command line compiling parameter. We've also tried to see if any other known issue may be side related to this error, and as far as we understand, we haven't found anything either.

If we don't touch our project (that means our code, our .project files, etc...),  we uninstall Xcode 11 beta 4, and then we restore beta 2 (and or beta 3), we can compile (and thus testing afterwards) our solution without any problem again.

If we carefully uninstall beta 2 (and or beta 3) to reinstall beta 4 again, we're faced again with that strange and simple error.

So our question is:

**-Is it a known fact? Has Xcode 11 beta 4 (Swift (?)) compiler(s) ceased recognizing this '-fstack-protector-all' parameter ?**

Any hint about what can be causing this? We're carefully checking Xcode "command line tools" are pointing to the correct version every reinstall of Xcode.

Greetings and thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I just installed beta 5, and the problem just disappeared... Our complex solution builds from scratch again... ‍♂

Our team was afraid it might be some other thing... But luckily this time, beta 4 won't get any QA round, and will be completely skipped.

Answer (score 0):

I've read the apple release notes for that problem and can't find anything too.

I would suggest to wait, till the release date of XCode 11. Till that, you can use the running beta versions.
You can also use Apples Bug Reporting for that.

Comment: I don't like feeling I'm the only one suffering this compiling parameter issue after 6 days (since beta 4 was released). I mean, no google search shed any light... :(